# How to use inherited class method and maintain the subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm working through the [Building Skills in Object Oriented Design](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/oodesign.html) in python and am on the [wheel section](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019050504/http://buildingskills.itmaybeahack.com/book/oodesign-3.1/html/roulette/wheel.html) for roulette. We've created a "Bin" class as an extended class from frozenset which will represent each of the positions on the roulette wheel. We then create a tuple of 38 empty "Bins", and now have to create class methods to be able to add odds/outcomes to the Bins.

My problem is that I've not been able to create a method to modify the Bin in position without the result not reverting to the frozenset class.

My desired output is to have:

```
class Bin(frozenset):
     def add(self, other):
          ....do union of Bin class....

one = Bin(1, 2, 3)
two = Bin(4, 5)
one.add(two)
print(one)
>>> Bin(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**Stuff I've tried**

Extending the frozenset class with no methods defined/overridden

```
class Bin(frozenset):
     pass

one = Bin([1,2,3])
two = Bin([4,5,6])
print(one|two)
print(type(one|two))
```

Which returns

```
frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
<class 'frozenset'>
```

I would have expected that by extending the class and using one of the extended methods that the output would remain as the "Bin" class.

I've also tried overriding the __ ror__ & union methods with the same result. I've tried to create a method which to brute force return the desired output. This however does not allow me to change the tuple of Bins as it doesn't operate in place

```
class Bin(frozenset):

def add(self, other):
    self = Bin(self|other)
    return self
one = Bin([1,2,3])
two = Bin([4,5,6])
one.add(two)
print(one)
```

Which returns

```
Bin({1, 2, 3})
```

Any insight into where in falling down in my thinking would and/or recommendations of stuff to read for further insight would be great.

Comment: @chepner it's not `__xor__`, it's `__or__`.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I typed that :) I meant `__or__`.

Comment: (Fixing previous comment: ) `one` and `two` are `Bin` instances. `one | two` is equivalent to `one.__or__(two)`. You didn't define `Bin.__or__`, so this resolves to `frozenset.__or__(one, two)`, which always returns a `frozenset` instance, regardless of the more-specific types its arguments may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frozenset.__or__` (which is called by the default implementation of `Bin.__or__` when 'triggered' by `one | two`) has no idea that `frozenset` was subclassed by `Bin`, and that it should return a `Bin` instance.

You should implement `Bin.__or__` and force it to return a `Bin` instance:

```
class Bin(frozenset):
    def __or__(self, other):
        # be wary of infinite recursion if using | incorrectly here,
        # better to use the underlying __or__
        return Bin(super().__or__(other))

one = Bin([1, 2, 3])
two = Bin([4, 5, 6])
print(one | two)
print(type(one | two))
```

Outputs

```
Bin({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
<class '__main__.Bin'>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I had forgot that tried overriding Bin.__or__ but hadn't known how to overcome the recursion error. Thanks for clearing that up.  The other problem I have now is to create a method that changes the Bin in place. it seemed to me creating a method 'add(self, other): self |= other' should change in place but isn't

Comment: @kevin_insert_somethin_fun_here there is a built-in [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) method in `set` that supports this. But as `frozenset` is immutable, it's not supported for that.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz that makes sense. I guess what I'm confused about is why we would be directed to create a tuple of Bins (ie empty frozensets) and then try to populate the bins with an in place method. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this (to avoid infinite recursion):

```
class Bin(frozenset):
    def __or__(self, other):
        return Bin(frozenset(self) | other)
```